# What is the correct places to put bash aliases which should be available for everyone?

Tags: bash, aliases

What is the correct places to put bash aliases which should be available for everyone?

I want to set it up in such are a way that if some aliases are not available for somebody, it is because they overrode it themselves in their own settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/etc/bashrc
```

Most `.bashrc` files have this in them by default, so users can choose not to have any of your globals if they want, and anything they put after this inclusion will be overriden.

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Comment: Just to note - Ubuntu Lucid uses bash.bashrc